# Crash when deauthenticating Layer messaging android app with GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, layer

I'm trying to de-authenticate my App using following call.

```
layerClient.deauthenticate();
```

But I'm getting following crash.

```
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-11-thread-6
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdL(Unknown Source)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.unregister(Unknown Source)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at com.layer.sdk.internal.push.Gcm$2.a(Gcm.java:150)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at com.layer.sdk.internal.push.Gcm$2.a(Gcm.java:142)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at com.layer.lsdkb.lsdkc.c.run(RetryableTask.java:156)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-28 22:30:37.657 16814-20670/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I'm using following code to initialize my client.

```
if (layerClient == null) {

LayerClient.enableLogging(this.getApplicationContext());

LayerClient.Options options = new LayerClient.Options();

options.googleCloudMessagingSenderId(Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID);
options.historicSyncPolicy(LayerClient.Options.HistoricSyncPolicy.ALL_MESSAGES);

layerClient = LayerClient.newInstance(this, Constants.LAYER_APP_ID, options);

layerClient.registerConnectionListener(connectionListener);
layerClient.registerAuthenticationListener(authenticationListener);
}

if (!layerClient.isConnected())
layerClient.connect();
else if (!layerClient.isAuthenticated())
layerClient.authenticate();
```

I'm folloing this link for integration
https://developer.layer.com/docs/android/integration#installation-and-setup

Any help will be great.